# What is a person’s relationship to their cousin’s uncle

Tags: proper-nouns

I know a girl who is dating her cousin’s uncle. What is her relationship to him other than boyfriend girlfriend?

Answer (score 1):

Uncle on which side?  A cousin is a parent's sibling's child, so your own parent would also be your cousin's uncle, or possibly one of your own uncles.

For example, my father has a sister, who has a daughter.  She is my cousin.  My father is her uncle.  So my *cousin's uncle* (my cousin's mother's brother) could be my *father*.

If my father and his sister had another brother, then my cousin's uncle could also be *my* uncle.

If it's on the other side of the marriage (no blood relation) then there is no special name for it in English.  There are only names for blood relations, and for a limited group related to you by marriage in some way.  For example, my brother's wife is my *sister-in-law*, my wife's sister is also my *sister-in-law*, my wife's father is my *father-in-law* -- but my brother's wife's father is *no relation* (or possibly a *distant in-law*).

Which isn't say you can't have a special relationship with a distant in-law.   We just don't have special names for those relations.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at it is that she is dating her (mother or father)'s (sister or brother)'s (husband or wife)'s brother (assuming 'the other side of the marriage', as Andrew mentions).

This makes him her (uncle- or aunt-in-law)'s brother, or her (aunt or uncle)'s brother-in-law. Some people might even (informally) describe him as her father's brother-in-law.

But whether we trace the relationship through her cousin, or just through the older generation, there is no single word to describe it.